# How to use Expected values in symbolic solving

Tags: symbolic

How can I create a function that brackets off terms of an expectation value?  For example, I have :

```
f = a[x] + c1*b[x] + c2*c[x];
g = Expand[f*f];
```

> ```
> a[x]^2 + 2 c1 a[x] b[x] + c1^2 b[x]^2 + 2 c2 a[x] c[x] + 2 c1 c2 b[x] c[x] + c2^2 c[x]^2
> ```

But I want to optimize the expected value of `g[x]` over `c1`, `c2`.  So I need a function that does something like this:

> ```
> exp[g] -> < (a^2) > +2 c1 < ab > +c1^2 < (b^2) > +2 c2 < ac > +2 c1 c2 < bc > +c2^2 < (c^2) >
> ```

...so that I can `Solve` for the optimum expected value of `g[x]` in terms of `a[x]`, `b[x]`, `c[x]`.

Comment: What do you mean with `<a^2> `and other such notations? Are you averaging them? If yes, can you specify, over which interval, with which weight? If not, please explain, what is it?

Comment: I'm using regular mathematical notation for an expectation value.  <.> mean the average value of a function over it's entire domain.  The actual domain/weights aren't relevant because I'm not explicitly evaluating the averages; I want the answer in terms of the expected (average) values of combinations of a[x],b[x],c[x].

Comment: OK, then answer please the rest of my question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what other info you need.  I want to find the expectation value of g[x], optimized over c1 and c2, in terms of the expectation values of: a[x], b[x], c[x], a[x]*b[x], b[x]*c[x], and a[x]*c[x].

Comment: Well, I in fact did not read your reply to the end. I in between gave the answer below. Have a look.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my interpretation:

```
Clear[split, exp];
split[expr_, v_] := Times @@@ GatherBy[Power @@@ FactorList[expr], ! FreeQ[#, v] &];
exp[expr_, var_] := First[#] AngleBracket[Last[#], var] &@ split[#, var] & /@ 
   List @@ Expand[expr] // Total

exp[f*f, x]
(*
〈a[x]^2, x〉 + 2 c1 〈a[x] b[x], x〉 + c1^2 〈b[x]^2, x〉 + 
  2 c2 〈a[x] c[x], x〉 + 2 c1 c2 〈b[x] c[x], x〉 + c2^2 〈c[x]^2, x〉
*)
```

I borrowed `split` from the `f` in my answer to [How to separate factors by dependent variables (arguments)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64389/how-to-separate-factors-by-dependent-variables-arguments/64401#64401)  I included the variable as a second argument to `AngleBracket`; omit if desired.  I also left the argument `x` to `a[x]` etc. in place instead of stripping them.  In my imagination of how I would use this, I would want them in.  But they may stripped with the replacement rule `h_[var] :> h` inside the function definition.  Or remove all `x` with optional post-processing:

```
exp[f*f, x] /. h_[x] :> h /. AngleBracket[e_, x] :> AngleBracket[e]

(*〈a^2〉 + 2 c1 〈a b〉 + c1^2 〈b^2〉 + 2 c2 〈a c〉 + 2 c1 c2 〈b c〉 + c2^2 〈c^2〉 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f = a[x] + c1*b[x] + c2*c[x];
g = Expand[f*f] /. {a_[x]*b_[x] -> 〈a b〉, a_[x]^2 -> 〈a^2〉}
```

Have fun!