# How to separate factors by dependent variables (arguments)?

Tags: argument-patterns

How can I separate factors in an expression by their dependent variables?  For example:

```
expr = b * c[2] * a[x] * 2 * x^2 * g[x,y] * z[r] * D[q[x], {x, 4}];
```

I need function that will separate the factors independent and dependent on a specified variable, like so:

```
f[expr, x]
```

> ```
> {2b*c[2]*z[r], a[x]*(x^2)*g[x,y]*D[q[x], {x,4}]}
> ```

```
f[expr, y]
```

> ```
> {2b*c[2]*z[r]*a[x]*(x^2)*D[q[x], {x,4}], g[x,y]}
> ```

Can this be done?

As sub-question, I tried this approach, and I am puzzled as to why it didn't work.  It separates the x-independent factor into several factors, and I can't understand why my code would do that.

```
g = a[x]^2 + 2 c1 a[x] b[x] + c1^2 b[x]^2 + 2 c2 a[x] c[x] + 2 c1 c2 b[x] c[x] + c2^2 c[x]^2 + a[x] b[x] c[x] ;
terms = Replace[#, HoldPattern[Plus[w___]] :> w] & /@ {g};
pairs = terms /. HoldPattern[q1___ r__ q2___ /; FreeQ[{r}, x]] :> {r, q1*q2}
```

> $$\left\{a(x)^2,\{2,\text{c1},a(x)
>    b(x)\},\left\{\text{c1}^2,b(x)^2\right\},\{2,\text{c2},a(x)
>    c(x)\},\{2,\text{c1},\text{c2},b(x) c(x)\},a(x) b(x)
>    c(x),\left\{\text{c2}^2,c(x)^2\right\}\right\}$$

What'd I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that factors the expression with [`FactorList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FactorList.html), in case it is not already factored, and gathers them.

```
Clear[f];
f[expr_, v_] :=  Times @@@ GatherBy[Power @@@ FactorList[expr], ! FreeQ[#, v] &]
```

I applied [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) to the derivative operator `D`, since it was unevaluated in OP's example output - hardly important, I think.

```
expr = b*c[2]*a[x]*2*x^2*g[x, y]*z[r]*Inactive[D][q[x], {x, 4}];

f[expr, x]
(* {2 b c[2] z[r],  x^2 a[x] g[x, y] Inactive[D][q[x], {x, 4}]} *)

f[expr, y]
(* {2 b x^2 a[x] c[2] z[r] Inactive[D][q[x], {x, 4}],  g[x, y]} *)
```

Below is a case where the input has not been factored.  It also works on expressions in which no factor is missing a particular variable (see `f[expr2, y]`).

```
expr2 = x^2 a[y] + 2 x y a[y] - x a[y] g[x, y] - 2 y a[y] g[x, y];

f[expr2, x]
(* {a[y],  (x + 2 y) (x - g[x, y])} *)

f[expr2, y]
(* {1,  (x + 2 y) a[y] (x - g[x, y])} *)
```

---

**Update re added sub-question**

Let's take a simple case, say the term `2 c2 a[x] c[x]`. We get:

```
2 c2 a[x] c[x] /. HoldPattern[q1___ r__ q2___ /; FreeQ[{r}, x]] :> {r, q1*q2}
(*  {2, c2, a[x] c[x]}  *)
```

Now, what did `r__` match?  A [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sequence.html), because of the [`BlankSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankSequence.html) (double underscore).  In particular `r` represents `Sequence[2, c2]`.  The replacement expression `{r, q1*q2}`becomes

```
{Sequence[2, c2], Sequence[]*Sequence[a[x] c[x]]}
(*  {2, c2, a[x] c[x]}  *)
```

What you want to do is this:

```
2 c2 a[x] c[x] /. HoldPattern[q1___ r__ q2___ /; FreeQ[{r}, x]] :> {Times[r], q1*q2}
(*  {2 c2, a[x] c[x]}  *)
```

Putting `Times` around `r` causes the sequence of factors to be multiplied.

Comment: Thank you, that was perfect.  I added a sub-question, because I don't understand why something else I tried didn't work.  I didn't post as a separate Question because it's more discussion I need than a syntactical answer.

Comment: @JerryGuern You're welcome.  See my update for an explanation of your replacement rule.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but now I don' t understand why the q1*q2 works the way it did.  If I change the end of my expression to {Times[r], {q1}, {q2}} the results show {} for every q1 and a sequence for every q2, for example {a[x], b[x]} for the 2nd term.  Given that, q1*q2 in the original expression should NOT yield a[x]b[x] but it does.  So I'm still not understanding some part of how this works.

Comment: @JerryGuern I didn't state it exactly, but it's weakly implied that `q1` is `Sequence[]` (matches no factors before `r`) and `q2` is `Seqeunce[a[x], c[x]]`.  The `*` means that `q1*q2` is `Times[q1, q2]`, which multiplies the elements of the sequences `q1` and `q2`.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this would work.

```
f[expr_, v_] := {Select[expr, (MemberQ[#, v, -1]) &], 
                 Select[expr, (! MemberQ[#, v, -1]) &]}


f[expr,x]
(* {x^2 a[x] g[x,y] (q^(4))[x], 2 b c[2] z[r]} *)

f[expr,y]
(* {g[x,y], 2 b x^2 a[x] c[2] z[r] (q^(4))[x]} *)
```

This will only work, without modification, on expressions where all of the elements are at level one (i.e. of the form `head[e1,e2,...]` where head may be something like `Times`, in this case, or `Plus` or `List`).

A more cryptic alternative that doesn't repeat code.

```
f[expr_, v_] := Head[expr] @@@ GatherBy[List @@ expr, MemberQ[#, v, -1] &]
```

Comment: I ran into a strange problem with this.  It doesn't work right if there's no x-independent factor.  f[2 a[x], x] works perfectly, returning {a[x], 2}, but f[a[x], x] returns {a[], a[x]}.

Comment: Well, there technically aren't any terms at level -1 in the second case that do not contain x.  Since the `Head` of the expression is `a` in this case it returns `a[]` indicating the missing terms. In the case of 2a[x] the head is `Times`. Depending on what you want you could add `/.Head[expr][]:>Sequence[]` which will remove the term.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f, x, y, z, q, expr];
expr = b*c[2]*a[x]*2*x^2*g[x, y]*z[r]*D[q[x], {x, 4}];
f[expr_, v_] := Pick[expr, (MemberQ[#, v, -1]) & /@ (List @@ expr), #] & /@ {True, False}

f[expr, x]
(* {x^2 a[x] g[x,y] (q^(4))[x], 2 b c[2] z[r]} *)
f[expr, y]
(* {g[x,y], 2 b x^2 a[x] c[2] z[r] (q^(4))[x]} *)
```

Comment: @kgugler  Same problem with this Answer.  f[2 a[x], x] works perfectly, returning {a[x], 2}, but f[a[x], x] returns {a[], a[x]}